# Make the UIImageView blur

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am having a View1 which has a `UIImageView` where I am loading a `UIImage`. When I am pressing a button in the View1 , I am adding a subview called View2 which has 2 buttons.

And I am making my second view as transparency using the alpha value like below.

```
[_view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
_imageView.alpha = 0.4;
```

That is ok. But What I want to do is, When I am adding the second subview, the first view is visible. Decreasing the alpha value will result in brightness of it. But I want to display the  imageview in the first view little blur. I need to set the alpha value as well as make the background image view blur. Can Anyone tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a look at this class that promises to implement blurring for images under iOS: https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```
 public extension UIImageView {

   public func blur(withStyle style: UIBlurEffectStyle = .light) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
    addSubview(blurEffectView)
    clipsToBounds = true
  }

}
```